# NoSuchMethodException while using JAVA Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, nosuchmethoderror

Hi I'm trying to use reflection to invoke a method and update the setter value of that method. But I'm getting NoSuchMethodException while ivoking that method.
I've updated the code. I'm so sorry for the errors in the previous code. I've refractored the code. The exception occurs when the setMethod of the class accepts primitive type arguments.

```
private static Object performMapping( Class voClass, Class[] clazz, Object voObject, Object data,String fieldType ){
    voClass.getMethod( "set" + fieldType, clazz ).invoke( voObject, data );
    return voObject;
}
private static Object mapField(ResultSet rs){
    Class voClass=Class.forName( "com.test.Test" );
    Object voObject = voClass.newInstance();
    Class[] doubleArrayParamTypes = new Class[ 1 ];
    doubleArrayParamTypes[ 0 ] = Double.class;
    voObject = performMapping( voClass, doubleArrayParamTypes, voObject, rs.getDouble(fieldType.getColumn()), "Mark" );
}
/* This is my Class. I need to set the Mark. But it is primitive double. Is it possible to set the mark using the above code? */
public class Test{
        private double mark;
        public double getMark() {
            return mark;
        }
        public void setMark(double mark) {
            this.mark = mark;
```

Comment: -1 for posting faulty code and obfuscating beyond debugability.

Answer (score 1):

What I see is that you pass `setAddress1` and concatenate it with `set`, thus getting `setsetAddress1`. Either pass the property name and capitalize it, or remove the `set` from the concatenation.

Also, the code you have provided won't compile. You can't have a variable called `class`

Comment: That was a mistake when I copied the code to this forum it is just setAddress1

Answer (score 0):

A shot from the hip, but aren't you trying to get the method `setsetAddress1`?

(`"set" + methodName`)

Comment: That was a mistake when I copied the code to this forum it is just setAddress1

Comment: So why do you run "set" + methodname? Why not just send in the method name implicitly, you did you in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works. You had two bugs (except for the syntactical class-name error):

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    Test() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
            SecurityException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {

    }

    private void m() throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {

        Class[] doubleArrayParamTypes = new Class[1];
        doubleArrayParamTypes[0] = Double.class;
        Class clazz = Class.forName("com.test.Test");
        Object voObject = clazz.newInstance();
        Double data = 5.0;

        performMapping(clazz, "Address1", doubleArrayParamTypes, voObject, data);

    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        new Test().m();
    }


    /* Reflection to set the data */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void performMapping(Class clazz1, String methodName, Class[] clazz,
                                Object voObject, Double data)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
            NoSuchMethodException {
        for (Method m : clazz1.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(m.getName()+ " " + Arrays.toString(m.getParameterTypes()));
        }
        clazz1.getMethod("set" + methodName, clazz).invoke(voObject, data);
    }

    public void setAddress1(Double arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

1. As pointed out by the other authors, you **added "set" two times** to the method name
2. You **tried to pass a `String`** `String data="TestData";` as argument, even though you specified that the **argument should be of type `Double`**: `doubleArrayParamTypes[ 0 ] = Double.class;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My method performMapping has to accept data of type Object. The exception setAddress1(java.lang.Double) is not there. But actually that method is there.